# No me sale la interfaz de Tkinter en el .exe pero desde Visual Studio si

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, interfaz

Soy nuevo en programar y he hecho un pequeño programa de unas 120 líneas de código y para hacerlo mas "simple" le he hecho una interfaz muy básica de tkinter que consta de un botón de Iniciar y otro de Detener. Cuando ejecuto el código de VS si me sale la interfaz, pero, he pasado el programa a .exe mediante Pyinstaller y cuando lo ejecuto no me aparece nada. Alguna idea? Perdona si es una pregunta tonta jejeje

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.